# Method for generating random numbers from continuous density

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random

I want to sample random numbers from a given continuous distribution. Probably acceptance rejection is the best approach, but a friend of mine came up with the following idea. I think this will work for discrete distributions but is too crude for continuous densities, but I wanted to ask someone how is really good at random number generation so this is why I post this here.

Consider you have a continuous density $f$ e.q. the density of the normaldistribution. Now create $N$ points $x_1 , ... , x_N$ on the x axis and
evaluate $f$ at these points: $f(x_1),..., f(x_N)$. Now multiply each of the evaluated points with $M$ (where $M$ is an integer big enough such that $M*f(x_k) \geq 1 \ \ \forall k$) and write the corresponding $x$ values $f(x)*M$ times in an array. Let´s take the standardnormaldistribution for an example: Let one of the $x_1 , ... , x_N$ be equal to zero, e.g. $x_i=0$ and choose $M=1000$. So  $f(0)*M \approx 0.4*1000 = 400 $. Now write the $0 \ 400$ times in your array. Proceed like that with all the other points $x_1 , ... , x_N$ . If you now choose some indices of the array randomly (uniform) you should get normally distributed random numbers.

So what do you say to this approach?

Comment: This is not very efficient (because of $M$) or accurate (because of $x_n$), but it is essentially correct. @benguin's answer (if you omit "that is also defined on $[0,1]$" to fit your case) is the correct way of sampling if you have the inverse of the cumulative distribution function. If not, your friend's method of approximating the cdf by a piecewise linear function might work. But you should still avoid $M$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that slight error in my answer regarding $[0,1]$, dunno why I said that >.< Anyways, even if you don't have $F^{-1}$, one possibility would be using numerical methods to numerically integrate $f$ to obtain $F$. Once you have $F$, you can find $F^{-1}$ by finding the inverse at various points. Notice that $F^{-1}(y) = x$ implies $F(x) = y$ so can find $x$ by plugging in a random value and then use a binary search until you find the correct $x$ that gives you $y$; this is possible since $F$ is an increasing function.

Comment: After that, you'll have a nice table of values for $F^{-1}$..this might be a bit of work to do initially, but it's a pre-computation you can do ahead of time and that you only need to do once. From there, when you need to actually calculate $F^{-1}(x)$, find the values in the table that $x$ is inbetween and interpolate the result.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a random number generator capable of picking any real number between $0$ and $1$, say it is a function called $rand()$. Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function for the probability density function $f$. Then you can simply call
$$F^{-1}(rand()),$$

in order to generate the elements of your array.